# Delay in display and hide div which contain gif image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem in making div visible and hide.
Following is my design..

```
<div class="sidebar_contents_container inactive_step" id="step-trip-mode">
<div id="Progressbar" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:999;background: rgba(0,0,0,0);display:none;">
    <div style="background-image:url('../images/progress_bar.gif');width:8%;height:17%;top:50%;left:50%;position:fixed;"></div>
</div>
<div class="settings_container">
    <div class="header">Register Your Device Id</div>
    <div class="intro-content">
        <div class="intro-content-middle">
            <span class="title" style="text-align: center;padding-right: 155px ">Device Id <font color="red">*</font>:</span>
            <div style="margin: 2px;">
                <!--<font size="4">Device Id : </font><font size="3" color="red">*</font></br>-->
                <input id="device_Id" type='text' class="txtbox" placeholder="Device Id"style="width:250px;height: 40px;"/disabled>
                <div style="color:red;visibility: hidden;">Device</div>
            </div>
            <span class="title" style="text-align: center;padding-right:140px;">Device Sim<font color="red">*</font>: </span>
            <div style="margin: 2px;">
                <input id="device_sim_number" type='text' class="txtbox" placeholder="Device Sim"style="width:250px;height: 40px;" maxlength="15"/>
                <div style="color:red; visibility: hidden;" id="device_sim_number1">Field can not be Blank.</div>
            </div>
            <span class="title" style="text-align: center;padding-right:140px;">First Name <font color="red">*</font>: </span>
            <div style="margin: 2px;">
                <input id="txtFName" type='text' class="txtbox" placeholder="First Name" style="width:250px;height: 40px;" maxlength="100"/>
                <div style="color:red;visibility: hidden;" id="txtFName1">Field can not be Blank.</div>
            </div>
            <div style="/* margin: 30px; */position: absolute;width: 98%;bottom: 35px;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="/* margin: 30px; */position: absolute;width: 98%;bottom: 35px;">
        <button id="SaveDeviceData" type="submit" class="btn-active" onclick="Checkvalidation2()" >Register</button>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Please consider these only with design perspective I am not mentioning whole code.

**Key Note here is I have created div which contains my GIF inside a div and I want to make it visible and hidden using jquery.**

What i have done to control visibility using jquery.

```
function Checkvalidation2(){
  $("#Progressbar").css('display','block');
  save();
}

function save(){
  testing();
}

function testing(){
  $("#Progressbar").css('display','none');
}
```

By using above code What i have faced so far is gif is not display. And if I just use  `$("#Progressbar").css('display','block');`  and do not make it's display 'none' it loads after 10 second or more.

But, I am getting that element on my web page.

Comment: dont solve your proble, but is better show() and hide() is more efficientdi

Comment: ^ https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: show the gif while doing what? Clicking the register button?

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a difference between "visibility: visible/hidden" and "display: block/none".

Comment: @ZombieChowder Yes.And hiding it after function complition

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use show() and hide() as mentioned by Alvro and Marty.

Secondly, your gif may be large and taking time to load. You can load it faster by preloading it in this manner

```
<div class="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

        if (document.images) {
            img1 = new Image();
            img2 = new Image();
            img3 = new Image();

            img1.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-001.gif";
            img2.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-002.gif";
            img3.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-003.gif";
        }

    //--><!]]>
</script>
```

I got this code from [here](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). It also has some other ways to preload images but the one I pasted above is the easiest imho.

You should also compress your gif to reduce its size. There are a number of online image compressors.

All the best.

Comment: My Gif is having 28.7Kb size.

Comment: Hmm.. Guess this will be tough then without the entire code